# Escaping problems in SimpleXML XPath query

Tags: php, jquery, xpath, attributes, simplexml

I am retrieving data from an XML file in PHP using an XPath like:

```
$xml -> xpath('///Region[@country="Spain"]/..');
```

This works fine. Now I am constructing the attribute query from an AJAX request like:

```
$attributeQuery = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($queryArray); $i++){
    $attributeQuery .= '@'.$keys[$i].'="'.addslashes($values[$i]).'"'; //outputs `@key="value"`
    if ($i + 1 != count($queryArray)){ //string needs another ' and ' if not last element
        $attributeQuery .= ' and ';
    }
}
$path = '///Region['.$attributeQuery.']/..';
```

This works fine when I have standard one-word country names. Trouble starts when I am looking for names containing single quotes like: `Lao People's Democratic Republic`. My query constructor returns:

```
'///Region[@country="Lao People\'s Democratic Republic"]/..'
```

in that case, which also works fine when I hard code it into the xpath-request, yet when I use the `$attributeQuery`-variable like `$xml -> xpath($path);` it fails and returns an empty result? The node in question does exist in my XML (it is found in the hardcoded query...):

```
...
<Region continent="Asia" country="Lao People's Democratic Republic" state="" subcontinent="South-Eastern Asia" />
...
```

To be honest I am a little puzzled about what might be causing this, I guess it is some escaping issue, but I have no clue where it is coming from. Also I do not understand why the hardcoded string will work and using the variable won't? Is there something about the inner workings of `addslashes` that I am missing here?

**EDIT:**

So, what I found out is that removing the `addslashes` from my query string concatenation fixes my problem as somehow the values inside my `$_GET` seem to be escaped already. Strangely I do have Magic Quotes turned off (checking it at runtime also returned `0`) and from what I can read in the documentation the only things that should happen to my Strings is that they will be URL-encoded by jQuery before being sent client-side and URL-decoded before being processed server-side.

So what is happening is the following, i do this in my JS:

```
params.country = $(this).val(); //returns "Lao People's Democratic Republic"
$.getJSON('getMapData.php',params,function(data){...
```

The server is doing the following:

```
$vals = array_values($_GET);
$keys = array_keys($_GET);
```

with the values in `$vals` somehow magically escaped already.

Although things are working fine at the moment, could anybody shed a light on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

From the [**php.net comments**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php#106361):

> If you want to search for quoted values use the xpath concat function.
>
> ```
> $xml->xpath('//zone[@country=concat("Cote d", \''', "Ivoire")]');
> ```

So for yours (I guess the escaping char in the comment is in the wrong order):

```
$xml->path('///Region[@country=concat("Lao People", '\'', "s Democratic Republic"]/..'
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the "problem" for me seems to be that although I have disabled Magic Quotes via `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
` (a runtime check will also return `0`) my `$_GET` values will still be escaped automatically (so that simply removing the `addslashes` fixed my problem). Do you have any idea why this might be happening? As far as I can tell $_GET should only be `urldecode`d, right?

Comment: Yes it is passed through `urldecode`. Hmm I can't tell it from here tell  what actually happens, maybe the AJAX call is to blame?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, yet I cannot find anything on that in the jQuery-docs, all it says is that data will be url-decoded before sending the request. I'll edit my question.